# on each button click, change content in a containing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, stage

Can anyone give me some directions / links to where/how you build a function that change content in a containing div when you click a button.

exsample:

I have 7 "stages" in a scene(which is my container div), and every time you click the button "next" it should change from stage1 to stage2 
stage2 to stage3
stage3 to stage4

etc.

Hope it makes sense

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Thats the thing, I need to make the code, sorry. I would like to know how to execute this idea.

Comment: on page refresh should the stage change to stage1 or it should retain the current value?

Comment: It should retain the value. So it gets the content from stage2 into the scene and so on. Kinda like this http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/24/

But it should work on one button only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).on('click','#next',function(){
  var str = $("#scene").text();
  var lastChar = str.substr(str.length - 1);
  lastChar++;
  $("#scene").text("Stage"+ lastChar);
});
```

Comment: Nice, but how do I control what should be loaded in these stages?

Lets say that in stage1 there is 2 images but in stage2 I have 4 images plus other html elements :P

Comment: try to use ajax with jquery, it is very useful in this case.